# How to disallow URLs by query string in array format

Tags: robots.txt, url-parameters

I want to disallow all URLs with a certain query parameter in array format.

For example I have this kind of URL:

```
https://example.com/site/?param[index]=1&param[index2]=5
```

and I do not want all crawlers to crawl site with `param` parameter in all array variations.

Second question: Is it possible to disallow only if certain array parameter occurs? For instance, `param[index3]`? (I do not need it, but it could be useful for other people)

Comment: Is it always the path `/site/`? Are there other parameters than `param`? Are the `param` parameters always at first position, directly after the `?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robots.txt syntax doesn't support this.

The closest you can get would be to add `<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX">` to any page with that parameter in the query string.